# Reading values in html (response) with Ajax

Tags: javascript

I get this html as response when i post api call, so i want to know how i can read **client_id** and **session_token** with jquery or some simple javascript code??

```
function getNewsFeed(d) {
    var c = {
        page_num: b,
        num_events: d,
        return_as_html: true,
        source: "web"
    };
    TAGGED.api.call(c, check)
}
```

Now want to check things:

```
function check() {
    // checking here
}
```

> ["{\"stats\":\"ok\",\"dia\":\"44\",\"result\":{\"success\":true,\"session_token\":\"969ndg1ai0c43034\",\"next_event_id\":0,\"client_id\":1314852}}"]

I dont have JSON so cant read it with JSON.parse
**i tried using but in firebug it does not show JSON**

i get same code in response and html when i check it with firebug.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to make the call so we can answer better.

Comment: You don't have JSON as in, you're using IE6 or what? `JSON.parse` is part of any modern browser implementation. If the `[]` are part of the response, pass the first item of the array to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Why you can't use JSON.parse?

Comment: If you're accepting jQuery, just use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) but if the native JSON parser didn't work, your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: The response is not HTML, as you said yourself, it looks like JSON. Even if the browser does not support the native `JSON` interface, you can always include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). Note that the response is an array with a string where the string itself contains JSON as well. So you have to parse the response twice, once to get the array and then the string inside the array.

Comment: yes its giving this in html and response in firebug

Comment: `["{\"stats\": ...]` is NOT HTML.

Comment: You can get a json parser in http://www.json.org/

Comment: Im my self confused but its giving it in html and response

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. If you refer to the names of the tabs in Firebug's panels, then don't care about it. It's just confusing if you mention it.

Comment: @FelixKling can u post small check function for this?

Comment: If you have the data, then it's just `var result = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data)[0]).result;` and then you can access the information with `result.client_id` for example.

Comment: ok i will try now thanks you help me some how

Answer (score 2):

If you can be sure there are not going to be certain special characters in your values, you can split by comma, then by colon, and strip out non-matching characters...

```
str = '["{\"stats\":\"ok\",\"dia\":\"44\",\"result\":{\"success\":true,\"session_token\":\"969ndg1ai0c43034\",\"next_event_id\":0,\"client_id\":1314852}}"]'

// replace all characters that are not letters, numbers, underscore, colon or comma
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_:,]/g,'')

// get array of key value pairs
all = str.split(',')

// create empty opts object to store final data
opt = {}

// loop through array of key value pairs
for(i in all){

    // split into key value array
    bits = all[i].split(/:/)

    // assign to opt object
    opt[bits[0]] = bits[1]

}

// access values vie keys of opt
alert(opt.client_id+": "+opt.session_token)
```

Comment: im not able to get this html in codes. my question how to read them.. first i need get it and then i can replace it with your codes

Comment: @deerox: The response is probably passed as argument to the callback, i.e `check`. Doesn't the API you use provide documentation with examples? Maybe they even already parse the data for you and you asked the whole question for nothing...